# Codeigniter get user details after usertype have been differentiated

Tags: codeigniter

Iam new in codeigniter and am currently working on a project and i have already seperated the users accorf=ding to their usertypes. But the thing is i cannot get the details of other users except the admin. Iam in a total confusion at the moment. Can someone please help me??

Comment: Add more description. add some sample code to understand better.

Comment: Seems more like general conditional messup. Probably you are somewhere using something like : if ( isAdmin() ){ //get other user details }. So if you are not logged in as admin you are bypassing the above code. Try providing relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

Add where condition in sql query -

`$this->db->where('usertype!=','admin')`;